# How do you deploy a Node.js app from GitHub to Google App Engine?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, heroku

I'm trying to switch over from the free tier of Heroku to the free tier of Google App Engine. With Heroku, I had it set up so that when I pushed to master on GitHub, it would automatically deploy to Heroku. I am trying to set up this behavior on Google App Engine.

I was able to get my GitHub repo synced up with the Google Cloud Platform Development tool, but I am unable to figure out how to deploy it from there. I have been Googling for a few hours, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your project for automated deploying using CircleCI tool (it's free for open source projects). Follow these instructions: https://circleci.com/docs/google-cloud-platform/